# How to change styles of a webpage in wxWebView in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to change the background color and font size of my webpage in the [wxWebView](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_web_view.html) widgets but it seems that the [SetFont](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a9ab11e7da57a1d08918aa75fc33f6ad3) and [SetBackgroundColor](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a37219df52734626e23401fd83b25d8a0) does not work. Should I write a separate CSS file and apply the styles there and add it the page source?

```
ctrl_ = wxWebView::New( parent, wxID_ANY, wxWebViewDefaultURLStr, WXFUTAS_START_POS, wxDefaultSize, wxWebViewBackendDefault );

ctrl_->SetBackgroundColour( color ); // does not work!
ctrl_->SetFont( font ); // does not work too!
```

Another question is that is there any way to add a CSS file without changing the page content in webview?

Comment: Did you try refereshing ? Like calling `ctrl_->Refersh()` after setting font and backgroundcolor.

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, refreshing does not change anything

Comment: Ok, and what about using `Update` after refresh like `ctrl_->SetBackgroundColour( color );ctrl_->SetFont( font );ctrl_->Refresh(); ctrl_->Update();`

Comment: @JasonLiam I just tried that. That also does not help

Comment: @Reza, are you displaying some kind of HTML? Maybe all you need is to set all this there? Or use JS?

Comment: @Igor Yes I am displaying a webpage and I thought setting styles is possible from these functions but it seems that I need to use CSS or JS and add them to the page content. Right?

Comment: @Reza, or insert it in HTML